# Question regarding first theorem of isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, group-isomorphism

> Question  regarding the first theorem of isomorphism ?
>
> ## $b)\ $$\frac{GL_n(\mathbb{Z}) }{SL_n(\mathbb{Z})} \cong  \ ?$
>
> ## $d)\ $$\frac{GL_n(\mathbb{R}) }{SL_n(\mathbb{R})} \cong  \ ?$

## My  atttempt  :

For option  $d$, the map $f: GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to \{-1,1\}$ given by $f(A) = \mathrm{sign}(\det A)$ is a surjective homomorphism with $\ker f = SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and so by the first isomorphism theorem, $GL_n({\mathbb{R}})/SL_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \{-1,1\}$.

I don't  know the  other option $ b)$.

Comment: For d, you've got the kernel wrong. Think of $f(2I)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar  why did u take  $2I $?

Comment: Because this shows that the kernel is not $SL_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In (d) consider $f(A)=\det A$.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R})/SL_n(\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{R}-{0}$, by the map $A\longrightarrow det(A)$. In your case any matrix with positive determinant belongs to karnel.

Comment: @TusifAhmed Is $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ a typo? Or did you intend to do so?

Comment: @YourongZang, I am sorry. Of curse, it is a typo and I can't edit it now.

Comment: @TusifAhmed Great. I thought I understood the question incorrectly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part b), you could see $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})=\{X|\det(X)=\pm1\}$. Thus if you take your homomorphism $\varphi:GL_2(\mathbb{Z})\to\{1,-1\}$ as $\varphi(X)=\det(X)$ (you don't really need the sign function here since its determinant is a sign...). Now, by proving $\varphi$ is an isomorphism with a kernel $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, you could see that
$$GL_2(\mathbb{Z})/SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong\varphi(GL_2(\mathbb{Z}))=\{+1,-1\}$$

For d), you could consider a more general case $GL_n(\mathbb{F})/SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field.

Let the homomorphism, $\varphi:GL_n(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{F}$, be $\varphi(X)=\det(X)$ in which you replace all operations in $\mathbb{R}$ with corresponding operations in $\mathbb{F}$. You could see that $\varphi$ has a kernel $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$ since $\forall X\in SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, $\det(X)=1_F$ according to the definition of special linear groups.

Now by the first isomorphism theorem, it follows that 
$$GL_n(\mathbb{F})/\ker\varphi\cong\varphi(GL_n(\mathbb{F}))$$
Because $\varphi(X)$ can take any value except $0$, we could see $\varphi(\mathbb{F})=\mathbb{F}^\times$ which means
$$GL_n(\mathbb{F})/SL_n(\mathbb{F})\cong\mathbb{F}^{\times}$$
or in part d)
$$GL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_n(\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$$

Note that $\mathbb{Z}^\times=\{+1,-1\}$, though maybe this notation is not valid since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.